# Check if the first and the last letter of the string are the same(Python)

Tags: python, string, list, slice

I have a list of strings and I wanted to count how many words are having same first and last letter:

```
strings = ["Ana", "Alice", "Bob", "Alex", "Alexandra"]

count = 0 

for word in strings:
   if word[0] == word[-1]:
       count += 1

print(count)
```

It gives me a result 0, when its supposed to give 3, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: "a" does not equal "A".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `.lower` because "a" is not equal to "A".

```
strings = ["Ana", "Alice", "Bob", "Alex", "Alexandra"]

count = 0

for word in strings:
    if word[0].lower() == word[-1].lower():
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

And if you're into list comprehensions, this could also be written as:

```
sum(word[0].lower() == word[-1].lower() for word in strings)
```

`True` and `False` become 1 and 0 when summed.

Comment: @DanielHao.  I'm not sure what you mean.  If you type `strings = ....` followed by my code above, it will reply `3`.  Python lets you pass a generator to sum.

Comment: Yes.  What I mean it's the syntax - ```sum(.......)```  tech. speaking it's a generator expression not list comprehension.  because it's not building any list.  +1

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I misunderstood the point you were making. I tend to use "list comprehension" as a generic term for all the various `[..]`, `(..)`, `{..}` stuff, but I should have been more careful with my words here.